# One dimensional heat equation with multiple eigenfunctions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

To solve the heat equation $u_{t}=u_{xx} \,\, (!)$ which is defined for $x\in[0,1]$ and $t>0$. I want to find the solution which satisfies the boundary conditions $u_{x}(0, t)=u_{x}(1,t)=0$ and initial conditions $u(x,0)=3x^{2}$. I have attempted to find a solution in the form $u(x, t) = P(x)Q(t)$, then substituting this into $(!)$ we get $$P(x)\dot{Q}(t)=P''(x)Q(t) \iff \frac{\dot{Q}(t)}{Q(t)} = \frac{P''(x)}{P(x)} = \lambda = \text{ const.}$$ Thus we have separated this problem into two odes \begin{align}(1)&\colon \dot{Q}(t)=\lambda\,Q(t)\iff Q(t)=Ae^{\lambda t}\\ \\(2)&\colon P''(x)=\lambda\,P(x)\end{align} We solve $(2)$ as an eigenvalue problem using the boundary conditions $P'(0)=P'(1)=0$ thus for $\lambda>0$, we have the solutions $P(x)=Be^{\sqrt{k}x}+Ce^{-\sqrt{k}x}$, from boundary conditions we find the only solution is when $B=C=0$ thus there are no eigenfunctions for $\lambda>0$. Now consider when $\lambda=0$, $P(x) = B+Cx$, from boundary conditions we find that $B=0$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}$, so $P_{1}(x)=A$, hence we have the eigenvalue $\lambda_{n}=\lambda=0$ with corresponding eigenfunction $\phi_{n}(x)=1$. When $\lambda<0$, let $\lambda=-\omega^{2}$, $\omega>0$, which has solution $P(x)=B\cos{\omega x}+C\sin{\omega x}$, from boundary conditions we find that $B=0$ and that there is a non-trivial solution when $\omega=n\pi$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ so we have the solution $P_{2}(x)=A\cos{(n\pi x)}$. Thus for $\lambda<0$ we have eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}=-n^{2}\pi^{2}$ with corresponding eigenfunctions $\phi_{n}(x)=\cos{(n\pi x)}$.

Thus we have two sets of eigen-pairs, now my question is how do I put this back into my guessed solution $u(x,t)=P(x)Q(t)$? Am I correct is saying the solution therefore has the form \begin{align}u(x,t) &= P_{1}(x)Q_{1}(t)P_{2}(x)Q_{2}(t)\\ &= (A_{1})(A_{2}e^{0\cdot t})(A_{3}\cos{(n\pi x)})(A_{4}e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2}t})\\ &=A\cos{(n\pi x)}e^{-n^{2}\pi^{2} t}\end{align}

Or do we write it in another form?

Comment: no,its not correct,actually you will get linearly independent solution for each n,hence linear combination of all these solution is the general solution just like we do in 2nd order linear D.E,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick and dirty answer is that you now use superposition to build a solution to your equation which satisfies the desired initial condition. The philosophy is that since your equation is $Lu=0$ for a linear operator $L$, any linear combination of solutions is also a solution.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, define $\phi_n(t,x) = \cos(n \pi x) \exp(-n^2 \pi^2 t)$ and $\psi_n(x) = \phi_n(0,x)=\cos(n \pi x)$. (Note that $\phi_0 \equiv 1$, so I've really included all the eigenfunctions you mentioned.) Then your initial condition can be represented in terms of $\psi_n$ as

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\int_0^1 \psi_n(x) f(x) dx}{\int_0^1 \psi_n^2(x) dx} \psi_n(x) \equiv c_n \psi_n(x).$$

This is just a Fourier series, and in this special case you can do all the integrals explicitly. Then the solution to your heat equation is given by

$$u(t,x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n \phi_n(t,x).$$

For any $t \geq 0$ this will converge in the sense of $L^2$, since $f \in L^2$ and $|\phi_n(t,x)| \leq |\psi_n(x)|$. Checking whether it converges pointwise is a more delicate matter. At $t=0$ it probably doesn't, since the initial condition does not have a continuous periodic extension. Also note that your solution is necessarily rather weak, because your initial condition doesn't satisfy the boundary condition.

Addendum: I made an error; because the initial condition doesn't satisfy the boundary condition, the series above will not converge to $f$ even in $L^2$. But this means that you need to reformulate the problem anyway, because you have a problem with explaining what the equation means when the initial condition doesn't satisfy the boundary condition. This problem is not insurmountable (you just need the weak formulation of the problem), but it is essential to address it. In particular, it is actually rather special that the weak formulation of this problem makes sense, because the weak formulation of the corresponding homogeneous Dirichlet problem does *not* make sense (since the initial condition doesn't satisfy a homogeneous Dirichlet condition, either).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So in reality we just ignore the second eigenvalue-eigenfunction pair? ($\lambda=0$, $\phi_{n}=1$)

Comment: @user2850514 $\phi_0$ is the constant eigenfunction. (Note that $0 \in \mathbb{N}_0$.) I probably should have pointed out that I rolled it in with the rest in that manner.

Comment: @user2850514 Actually, I made a mistake; the series I wrote will *not* converge to $f$, because of the fact that the initial condition does not satisfy the boundary conditions. Linear combinations of cosines of half-integer frequency are dense (in $L^2$) only on the space of functions with vanishing derivative at the boundary, which your $f$ is not. Hence the cosine series for your $f$ will not converge to $f$ even in $L^2$; you must include sine terms, which will violate the boundary condition.  Why are you particularly interested in this situation?

Comment: This is a problem I have been set on a differential equations course, all the examples I have seen so far have only had a single eigenfunction however this one has more than one and I'm just not sure how to present my my solution in this case.

Comment: @user2850514 Among functions which satisfy the boundary condition, what I wrote down is the closest approximation, in the sense of $L^2$. But you will find that the sum I wrote down does not converge to $f$ at $t=0$.